# NLog Raygun - How to catch exception when calling SendInBackground

Tags: c#, nlog, raygun

I forked the NLog Raygun from Mindscape to provide more settings of Raygun in NLog.

A RaygunTarget is created and needs to override `Write` method as follows NLog document (https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/How-to-write-a-custom-target).

To send an exception to Raygun, follows the below code

```
protected override void Write(LogEventInfo logEvent)
{
    _raygunClient ??= (_raygunClient = CreateRaygunClient());
    ...
    _raygunClient.SendInBackground(exception, tags, userCustomData);
}
```

`SendInBackground` returns a Task which we can not mark `Write` method as `async void` because it's not the case of using `async void`.

Everything works fine. We have a swagger to have Healthcheck. I want to check if NLog Raygun is sent successfully but I don't know how to catch the exception in `SendInBackground` in case API Key is invalid. I mean is there a better way to test whether this RaygunTarget can send a message successfully to Raygun?

If I provide a setting called ThrowOnError and in `Write` method updated like this

```
protected override void Write(LogEventInfo logEvent)
{
    _raygunClient ??= (_raygunClient = CreateRaygunClient());
    ...
    var task = _raygunClient.SendInBackground(exception, tags, userCustomData);
    if (_setting.ThrowOnError) task.Wait();
}
```

It works but a question is: This is a good way to do that? Personally, I think it's not because it introduces a different behavior or side-effect based on a setting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of inheriting from `TargetWithLayout` then you can inherit from `AsyncTaskTarget`:

```
protected override Task WriteAsyncTask(LogEventInfo logEvent, CancellationToken token)
{
    _raygunClient ??= (_raygunClient = CreateRaygunClient());
    ...
    var userCustomData = base.GetAllProperties(logEvent);
    return _raygunClient.SendInBackground(exception, tags, userCustomData);
}
```

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/How-to-write-a-custom-async-target

Then you can hook into the NLog InternalLogger using `InternalLogger.LogWriter`, and forward to healthcheck-api.

There are plans to improve the API for NLog 5.0 so one can subscribe to an InternalLogger-Event and can also get more context details. Like Target-Name, Target-Type etc. See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/3350

Comment: Is it safe while inherits AsyncTaskTarget and configs async=true in config file? I saw on document said "Async attribute and AsyncWrapper
Don't combine the Async attribute and AsyncWrapper. This will only slow down processing and will behave unreliably"

Comment: I have another solution by move the code in `Write` method into another method which supports returning `Task` and make it `public`, `Write` method will call the new method and Health-check will call the new method from target. Is it good solution?

Comment: Yes you could just add `_raygunClient.SendInBackground(...).ContinueWith(t => ReportError(t.Exception), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted)`